# Revit C# Skip loading pyrevit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, revit, pyrevit

I just got into using C# finally on Visual Studio and its great.

I have a simple question. I have PyRevit loaded on my computer. When I run Debug on visual studio, PyRevit adds another 2 minutes in loading Revit. Since I am constantly running debug to test my application, it tends to add on a fair amount of time starting up Revit every time.

Is there a way of using c# to skip loading PyRevit every time during Debug?

Comment: Use the addin manager app listed here to disable pyRevit in debug: https://www.rhino3d.com/inside/revit/beta/reference/toubleshooting#search-for-conflicting-plugins

Comment: @EhsanIran-Nejad, please post this as the answer and I will check as the answer. Huge time saver!